# I need current easy to follow instructions for configuring spring integration kafka from XML

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration

The spring integration kafka model has changed sufficiently as it has been worked on and simplified that the extant demos, manuals, and instructions don't work any more. The current official demos are all built around annotations, which are cool, but largely unreadable, and are not appropriate for my architecture in which the jobs are deployed and managed separately from the java code.

Is there a ***current*** (2019) tutorial for configuring, in ***XML***, spring integrations producers and consumers?

For reference, here is an extract from my POM that details the versions I am using:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Edit: Note to down voters

The link on github was broken and is now fixed, per comment by Gary Russel in his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the [reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#spring-integration) not provide what you need?

For example:

```
<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter"
                                    kafka-template="template"
                                    auto-startup="false"
                                    channel="inputToKafka"
                                    topic="foo"
                                    sync="false"
                                    message-key-expression="'bar'"
                                    send-failure-channel="failures"
                                    send-success-channel="successes"
                                    error-message-strategy="ems"
                                    partition-id-expression="2">
</int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="localhost:9092" />
                    ... <!-- more producer properties -->
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

and

```
<int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="kafkaListener"
        listener-container="container1"
        auto-startup="false"
        phase="100"
        send-timeout="5000"
        mode="record"
        retry-template="template"
        recovery-callback="callback"
        error-message-strategy="ems"
        channel="someChannel"
        error-channel="errorChannel" />

<bean id="container1" class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="localhost:9092" />
                ...
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.config.ContainerProperties">
            <constructor-arg name="topics" value="foo" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>

</bean>
```

etc...

Comment: Thank you - directions to the reference manual is very useful.  I will know later today whether or not it is sufficient.

Comment: The [README on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka) says `>Documentation for this extension is contained in a chapter of the Spring for Apache Kafka Reference Manual` (but the link was broken - fixed).

Comment: I might add that this is MUCH simpler than the examples I have been wading through for the past three days. Kudos to the spring-integration team.

Comment: Thanks - the old version was based on a much harder to use Scala client.

Comment: In the old examples I have been using, there was a org.springframework.batch.integration.partition.MessageChannelPartitionHandler that was able to handle the kafka resources.  Is there an new equivalent? Should I submit a new question?

Comment: That's a Spring Batch component and has nothing to do with Kafka. But, yes, please ask a new question; I have to run so I won't be able to answer until tomorrow.