# What is the latest (2019) preferred way to integrate spring batch with kafka?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

This is a followup question to [I need current easy to follow instructions for configuring spring integration kafka from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55266408/i-need-current-easy-to-follow-instructions-for-configuring-spring-integration-ka/55266617)

Spring-integration-kafka has evolved a lot over the past few iterations, and many old examples no longer function.

In particular, this bean which bridges from the spring-batch world to the spring integration world will not instantiate, because the `KafkaTemplate` class does not implement `MessagingTemplate` . What is the current recommended way to accomplish this integration?

```
<bean id="partitionHandler" class="org.springframework.batch.integration.partition.MessageChannelPartitionHandler">
    <property name="stepName" value="fm-step0002.messager"/>
    <property name="gridSize" value="3"/> 
    <property name="messagingOperations" ref="kafkaTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

Here is a snip from my POM that shows the versions of the libraries I am using:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-integration</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MessagingTemplate` is a core Spring Integration component; it has nothing to do with the broker you are using (RabbitMQ, Kafka, JMS etc.).

You configure the template with a default channel (which is the input channel to the kafka outbound endpoint).

See the [batch documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#remote-partitioning) (click the XML button at the top of the document to change the examples from java to XML).

The example there applies to JMS, but the configuration is similar for Kafka.

```
<bean id="partitionHandler"
   class="org.springframework.batch.integration.partition.MessageChannelPartitionHandler">
  <property name="stepName" value="step1"/>
  <property name="gridSize" value="3"/>
  <property name="replyChannel" ref="outbound-replies"/>
  <property name="messagingOperations">
    <bean class="org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate">
      <property name="defaultChannel" ref="outbound-requests"/>
      <property name="receiveTimeout" value="100000"/>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>

<int:channel id="outbound-requests"/>
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter destination="requestsQueue"
    channel="outbound-requests"/>
```

Comment: Yes, but the bean MessageChannelPartitionHandler will not accept a KafkaTemplate in the messagingOperations property. I cloned MessageChannelPartitionHandler to make a KafkaMessageChannelPartitionHandler - The KafkaTemplate appears to be have one method `receive` that is missing/different signature from the interface MessagingTemplate

Comment: As I said, the handler doesn't get a template that has anything to do with Kafka, it gets a `MessagingTemplate`; that template sends a message to a channel; the subscriber to the channel is the outbound channel adapter, which, in turn, calls a `KafkaTemplate` (or `JmsTemplate`, or `RabbitTemplate`) to actually send the message to the broker. See the configuration I pasted into the answer (for JMS in that case). Just replace the jms adapter with a kafka adapter.

Comment: Got it ... MessageChannelPartitionHandler -> MessagingTemplate -> Outbound Channel Adapter -> KafkaTemplate (or other template) .